# Infinispan use Protobuf marhaller rather than AdvancedExternalizer for my cache

Tags: protocol-buffers, infinispan

I have been reading some documentation around infinispan and protobuf:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_data_grid/7.0/html/developer_guide/sect-protobuf_encoding

The problem is that it seems to only be related to HotRod queries and I cannot find anyway to use it as my serialization format.

Right now I have:

```
GlobalConfiguration globalConfig = new GlobalConfigurationBuilder()
        .serialization()
            .addAdvancedExternalizer(new MyExternalizer())
        .build();
```

My only problem with this approach is if I decide to change/remove fields in the object being cached it will be more difficult that it would be with protobuf to migrate.

Is it possible to use a protobuf implementation such as ProtoStreamMarshaller rather than an AdvancedExternalizer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can not enable indexing on the cache config and also not invoke any query functionality in the client